# Web App won't start after upgrading from 3.0.2 to 3.1.2

Tags: spring-security

I have a working 3.0.2 applicationContext-security.xml that uses a custom authenticator

```
<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="disabled">

</global-method-security>

<http use-expressions="true">

    <intercept-url pattern="/diagnostics/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />


    <form-login login-page="/genesis" default-target-url="/diagnostics/start-diagnostics"
      authentication-failure-url="/genesis?authfailed=true"
      authentication-success-handler-ref="customTargetUrlResolver"/>
      <access-denied-handler error-page="/genesis?notauthorized=true"/>

     <logout logout-success-url="/genesis"/> 
    <session-management session-authentication-error-url="/genesis"> 
        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1" expired-url="/genesis?sessionExpired=true"/> 
    </session-management>
</http>

<authentication-manager>
<authentication-provider ref="genesisAuthenticator">
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
</authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<beans:bean id="genesisAuthenticator" class="com.blackbox.x.web.security.Authenticator"/>
<beans:bean id="customTargetUrlResolver" class="com.blackbox.x.web.security.StartPageRouter"/>   

</beans:beans>
```

After upgrading to 3.1.2 my application will not start and I get the error message

"Configuration problem: authentication-provider element cannot have child elements when used with 'ref' attribute". I'm assuming that the problem lies with the

```
<jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"/>
```

element where data-source-ref points to a definition in my application-context.xml file.

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/genesis"/>
<property name="username" value="dbuser"/>
<property name="password" value="********"/>
```

What do I need to do to get this working. Dropping back to 3.0.2 is not really an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a custom AuthenticationProvider implementation you'll have to configure it in XML in "traditional" Spring way, because `<security:authentication-provider ref="yourImpl">` just points to bean which can authenticate *whatever* in *whatever way*, and don't really have to use `UserDetailsService` at all. In your example you tried to use `jdbc-user-service` which is just shortcut for creating `JdbcDaoImpl` bean.

So what you have to do is to assure that all `genesisAuthenticator` dependencies are resolved by yourself not Spring Security. That is you should either add `@Autowired setUserDetailsService(UserDetailsService userDetailsService)` method to your bean or configure it in XML like this (using [`id`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-jdbc-user-service) attribute):

```
<beans:bean id="genesisAuthenticator"
    class="com.blackbox.x.web.security.Authenticator">
  <property name="userDetailsService" ref="jdbcUserService"/>      
</beans:bean>

<jdbc-user-service id="jdbcUserService" data-source-ref="dataSource" />
```